# UIScrollView blocks all touches while zooming or scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I can't press any other buttons in the same window while UIScrollView is zooming with a pinch gesture or scrolling.  Is there any way to enable this behavior?  It's exactly like the scroll view has exclusive touch (though I tried setting it explicitly to `NO`).  I have a scroll view inside a view, and I would like it to scroll only while the user holds a scroll button.  Otherwise, panning with one finger enables freehand drawing.

Comment: What happens if you start with scroll disabled, until the button is tapped? I assume as soon as you start to scroll, the button gets un-pressed?

Comment: There is no problem if I do it that way.  The problem is, the touch is not received by the UIScrollView as long as I am touching somewhere else on the screen (I just sit there rubbing the screen with no movement).  If I just have a toggle button, it works as I'd expect.  All my other buttons behave the same way too.  They are not children of the scroll view either.

Comment: I see, it is the scrollview that doesn't get the touches. Perhaps the button itself or its parent view has exclusive touch?

Comment: Nope, I can press all the other buttons in any combination I want but as soon as I engage the scroll view, I can't push any of them.  Also, the reverse is true.  I could press two buttons at once, and then try to interact with the scroll view and nothing will happen.  Very unusual...

Comment: AHHH!!!  Wait...that was it...a view deep in the hierarchy had it (subview of the scroll view).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the answer was that I foolishly had a subview that had `exclusiveTouch` enabled among the subviews of the scroll view.