# IOS UIScrollView - scroll and click element at the same time

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with an button just outside the content area of the scrollView. The user has to scroll up and hold the spring effect which one finger and push the button with another finger. The problem is that the touch on the button is never detected.

Please see the illustration below

[image: The scroll view in it's initial state. the orange area is the scrollView, the white area the button]

*The scroll view in it's initial state. the orange area is the scrollView, the white area the button*

[image: The user is now scrolling and holding with one finger to overcome the spring effect of the UIScrollView, and want to click the button, which is currently not possible]

*The user is now scrolling and holding with one finger to overcome the spring effect of the UIScrollView, and want to click the button*

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to use this concept https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl

Comment: This is not an answer, but are you sure this is really what you want to do? This sounds like an awful user experience, and if it isn't part of some kind of puzzle game, I would strongly recommend against it.

Comment: @fzwo. This is a hidden gimmick feature, but as you said yourself; not a really helpful comment.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota. Thanks for your suggestion. It looks like the element being pulled down is not really a button or object the user can interact with? - I might be wrong, but in that case it will not solve my problem. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:
[UIScrollView blocks all touches while zooming or scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061528/uiscrollview-blocks-all-touches-while-zooming-or-scrolling)

Make sure you have multitouch set to YES on the scrollview and also don't have any subviews with exclusive touch enabled.